# How to change text dynamic in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]
[image]

at line 161,I want to insert my text in parameter t,but it won't change when i debug it.although the parameter tmp had alredy changed.

[image]

I want to change this Text in UI,when my parameter t changes.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Consider posting your code as _text_ rather than image.  This keeps our search engines happy.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your advice and encouragement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect to your specific issue, [Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert) is defined as:

> public string Insert (int startIndex, string value);

and returns a new string. In C#, strings aren't modified, new strings are created. In this way, they act like a value type, even though they're a reference type. In other words, once a string is created, it is never modified - it's 'immutable'. So, you need to store your newly created string.

In cases like this, I like to use the [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), as it allows me to get a slightly clearer representation of what the final string will look like.

```cs
var tmp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString ( e.Message );
t.text = $"{tmp}\n{t.text}"; // Note that a newline is represented as \n
```

Or, if you add the `System.Text` namespace; you could reduce it down to:

```cs
using System.Text;
...
t.text = $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString ( e.Message )}\n{t.text}";
```

Answer (score 0):

The `string` type in c# is immutable, therefore `Insert` returns a new string instead of modifying the current one.

Do:

```
t = t.text.Insert(0, tmp + "//n");
```

### See also

- *[How to modify string contents in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/modify-string-contents)*